# Moving and rotating using lerp does not change smoothly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move and rotate smoothly camera when character which I follow stops and continues moving. I can't understand why it turned out to be intermittent. I tried to count _time in update but it made no difference.

[Video of camera moving](https://youtu.be/UC8YGtzmUwE)

Camera moving code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEditor.PlayerSettings;
 
public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _positionInShelter;
    [SerializeField] private Quaternion _rotationInShelter;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _character;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
 
    private Quaternion _defaultRotation;
    private Vector3 _defaultPosition;
    private float _distanceX;
    private float _time;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        _distanceX = _character.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
        _defaultPosition = transform.position;
        _defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new(_character.transform.position.x - _distanceX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
 
    private IEnumerator InShelterPosition(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        _time = 0f;
        while (_time != 1f)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            _time += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, position, _time);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, _speed * _time);
        }
    }
 
    public void CameraInShelterPosition()
    {
 
        StartCoroutine(InShelterPosition(_positionInShelter, _rotationInShelter));
    }
 
    public void CameraDefaultPosition()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InShelterPosition(_defaultPosition, _defaultRotation));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're updating the position both in Update every frame and the coroutine every frame. I suspect they are fighting each other.

Comment: You've made a typo in the update loop. You need to specify what `new` thing you are creating. I assume the `Vector3` got eaten when you copied the code.

Comment: @Voidsay: It's a new syntax. If the type is implicit from the left-side, then you don't need to specify it.

Comment: It's not intuative but you need to use [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) to lerp rotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RetiredNinja said the problem was that in lerp i used current position not constant position.

Edited code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEditor.PlayerSettings;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _positionInShelter;
    [SerializeField] private Quaternion _rotationInShelter;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _character;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;

    private Quaternion _defaultRotation;
    private Vector3 _defaultPosition;
    private float _distanceX;
    private float _time;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _distanceX = _character.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
        _defaultPosition = transform.position;
        _defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new(_character.transform.position.x - _distanceX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }

    private IEnumerator InShelterPosition(Vector3 positionStart, Quaternion rotationStart, Vector3 positionEnd, Quaternion rotationEnd)
    {
        _time = 0f;
        while (_time != 1f)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            _time += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(positionStart, positionEnd, _speed * _time);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rotationStart, rotationEnd, _speed * _time);
        }
    }

    public void CameraInShelterPosition()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InShelterPosition(_defaultPosition, _defaultRotation, _positionInShelter, _rotationInShelter));
    }

    public void CameraDefaultPosition()
    {
        if (transform.position != _defaultPosition)
        {
            StartCoroutine(InShelterPosition(_positionInShelter, _rotationInShelter, _defaultPosition, _defaultRotation));
        }
    }
}
```